# Plugin similar to Taxonomy Drill-Down for custom fields?

Tags: custom-field, plugin-recommendation, query

Is there a plugin available that does for custom fields what [Scribu](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/205/scribu)'s excellent [Taxonomy Drill-Down](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/query-multiple-taxonomies/) (formerly called Query Multiple Taxonomies) does for taxonomies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used to have a plugin that did exactly this. It was called Custom Field Taxonomies. Then custom taxonomies happened:

http://scribu.net/wordpress/custom-field-taxonomies/change-of-direction.html

That said:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/query-custom-fields/

Let me know if you would like to adopt it.